# Compile error trying to put a unique_ptr into a map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a Load-Method which builds my unique_ptr (will be more than one later on) and a method to add these unique_ptr to my unordered map. But the code does not compile and I guess it has something to do with scoping...

Here is the code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        std::string Name;
};

using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>;


class MyContainer
{
    private:
        Map myMap;
        void AddItem(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> item)
        {
            myMap.emplace("test", item);
        }
    public:
        void LoadItems()
        {
            //Read a file ... do something before etc..
            std::unique_ptr<MyClass> someItem(new MyClass);
            someItem->Name = "FooBar";
            AddItem(someItem);
        }
};
```

This is one of the g++ error messages:

> error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp,
>   _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = MyClass; _Dp = std::default_delete]'

What is the best way to get this working? I tried changing the signature of the AddItem-method like so:

```
void AddItem(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>& item) //takes a reference now...
```

This leads to a real cryptic error message:

> In instantiation of 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const
>   _T2&) [with _U1 = const char (&)[5];  = void; _T1 = const std::basic_string; _T2 = std::unique_ptr]': e:\devtools\winbuilds\include\c++\4.8.3\bits\hashtable_policy.h:177:55:
>   required from 'std::__detail::_ ...

I suggest trying this piece of code on the fly here, to see the error messages: 
http://cpp.sh/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot copy a `unique_ptr`, because then it will not be unique. You have to move it - `AddItem(std::move(someItem));` and `myMap.emplace("test", std::move(item));`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to copy *unique_ptr* which is not allowed (that constructor is deleted as gcc says in the error). Instead of that you can try with *std::move*:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class MyClass
{
    public:
         std::string Name;
};

using Map = std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>;


class MyContainer
{
    private:
        Map myMap;
        void AddItem(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> item)
        {
            myMap.emplace("test", std::move(item));
        }
    public:
        void LoadItems()
        {
            //Read a file ... do something before etc..
            std::unique_ptr<MyClass> someItem(new MyClass);
            someItem->Name = "FooBar";
            AddItem(std::move(someItem));
        }
};
```

Be aware, do not use the moved object afterwards.

You can consider to use *shared_ptr* instead.